# How to connect to the centralized MySQL database from my django website?

Tags: mysql, django, distributed-computing, distributed-system, system-design

Lets say I have two systems that will runs a Django server and one system that will be a centralised database that will only contain database application running on this machine. How can I have two machines connect to same database i.e Read/Write from/to database? What software needs to be running on my MySQL database side so it can get the data from the server and return the data from the database in case of read query ?

**The question is how can two server make connection to a centralized database to read/write from it? What code/technology should be running on the database server to send/receive data?**

If there are to systems that are solely dedicated as a server and one as a database then how can I make a connection from my two server machine to the centralized database. Which technologies can help me in achieving this? What code should be run on the third machine and how the other two server makes connection to this database?

Comment: Why do you think you need any kind of "code/technology"? Just put the address of the db server in your DATABASES setting.

Comment: And I can't see what the "third" machine is here. You have one machine that is the db server, and one that is the web server; what's the third?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I meant that I have 2 instances of server both running my django website, but I want both of them to connect to same database running on my third machine which is also an instance of machine. My question is how can I achieve that cuz I have never worked on distributed system. So how can I connect both and then later can implement load balancers.

Comment: As I said, just put the address of the db machine into your DATABASES setting.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Are the centralised database implemented using this concept only?

Comment: I don't understand what that means.

Comment: What I mean is, we have multiple servers and each server is connected to each other such that the request comes in and can be directed to any server. How do we implement this. I mean is it handled by load balancers. Are the request that comes for a website directed to the any one of the server implemented using load balancers. Then how does it know about the list of machine that I have thats currently serving my website

Comment: That doesn't appear to have anything at all to do with your question. But yes, of course, that is handled by a load balancer; the way it would know about the machines is either because you tell it, or because you have some kind of service discovery mechanism. But, again, this appears to be completely outside the scope of this question.

Comment: I am an undergrad student in India, I don't understand the concept of system design until I implement all of it by myself. But since I don't have enough money and resource I can't develop my own distributed computing system. So what I am trying is to implement the concept using the linode nanode machines and amazon s3 storage

Comment: @DanielRoseman my original question was why do we need multiple databases(serving same data) then when we can have one database that can store everything and serve request using the database server

Comment: No-one said we did. As I and Akash have both said, in my case repeatedly, you just put the address of the shared db server in your DATABASES setting.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I don't find much good resources to learn system design in great detail online. Can you please suggest few online tutorials and courses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fail to understand why you need extra softwares/technology for this.. If all you want to do is make both your django servers access the shared database kn the third server, just point both your django servers to the server running your MySQL.. it should do the job..